# jQuery HiSRC plugin always loading retina images

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, retina-display

I'm using the HiSRC jQuery plugin to load larger images for retina displays. As a test, I set the larger images to bright red so that I can be certain of when they're loading and when they're not.

It seems, however, that the retina images are loading all the time, even when using FF on my 2009 model iMac.

I can also see in Firebug that the 'src' attribute in my page's HTML gets modified by the plugin so that the default image has been swapped with the retina one:

[image: Firebug]

All I'm using to call the script is the following:
`$(".hisrc img").hisrc();`

In my text editor however, I'd coded it like so:

```
<figure class="hisrc">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image/logo.png" data-1x="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image/logo-1x.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
</figure>
```

Here is a link to the site:
http://bit.ly/ITLq8L

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "data-2x" attribute for your retina image source.

The "data-1x" attribute replaces the (low resolution) default image with the standard resolution image.

Source: [HISRC documentation](https://github.com/teleject/hisrc/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: thanks for the tip, and sorry for the latest reply in history! I've added a 'data-2x' attribute but it still seems to be loading the 1x version. Going by the documentation, I'm guessing it's loading that due to the speed of my internet connection? Except I'm using a 3G connection (tethered to my computer) so I would have thought it would load the lowest resolution instead